# Negative Regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a negative regex in python with the module re (and findall) to capture a part of a string. I would like to capture a part of a string but when I find a specific character I don't capture anything, so with a negative regex.How could I do that ?

Input String :

```
9:00:00
10:00
```

I would like to use a negative regex in order to not capture anything if I find  ':' after a second number

I have tried:

```
 r'([0-9]{1,2})\s*:\s*([0-9]{1,2})\s*![:]'
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your code? What doesn't work?

Comment: Are you trying to split the text where your regex matches? That would be `import re` and then `re.split(pattern, string)`.

Comment: Could you please add some samples of what you want to achieve? And also include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Although the regex can be simplified more, but to maintain your approach, You may try this one ( Which will not mach anything if there is a second colon preceded by digits)

```
(?:^|\s)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})[^\d:]
```

And for the input string:

```
"7:00 or 8:00:00   5:33   9:05 45 7:00"
```

You get 4 group captured as : `7:00,5:33,9:05,7:00`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1gYgFh/13/)

Comment: sentence = "7:00 or 8:00:00"   
regex = r'(?!\d{1,2}\s*:\s*\d{1,2}:)\d{2}:\d{2}'
match = re.findall(regex, sentence)
print (match)

It's not working, why ?

Comment: You could remove the entire lookahead and it would still match the same way.

Comment: Sebastian Proske now it feels like it was a bit premature to answer this... beforehand, will delete it pretty soon.. unless i could understand further the reqs :s\

Comment: @77140B What output you exactly want for your given input "7:00 or 8:00:00" and for "7:00 or 8:00" ?

Comment: 7:00 or 8:00:00 : Output = [7:00]
7:00 or 8:00 : Output = [7:00, 8:00]

Comment: Seems like OP is looking for `(?<!:)\b\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}\b(?!:)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman you wouldn't catch `7:00` if you hadn't added a space in your test sample. That's sneaky.

Comment: 457:00 this is not a valid time is it ?

Comment: yes, but `7:00` is a string that should be matched. It isn't matched correctly.

Comment: I'm having an other issue with the string : "10:00a.m or 4:00 p.m" 
I use this regex '(?<!:)\b(\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(\d{1,2})\b(?!\s*:)\s*([.]?(a|p)\s*[.]?\s*m[.]?)?'
But if there isn't a whitespace between the number and the a (or p) it's not working, I think it's because of the \b but I don't see why.